# Why is this proof about sequences wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got no points for this in an exam, but they didn't tell me what is wrong. Any remark is helpful. I needed to prove this:

> Suppose that the sequence $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $l\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that the sequence
> $$v_n=\frac{u_1+\dots+u_n}{n}$$ also converges to $l$.

My proof was the following:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. As $u_n\rightarrow l$, we have that $\exists\: N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall\: n\geq N\enspace |u_n-l|<\varepsilon/2\:$,  also there is a $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{|u_1-l|+\dots+|u_{N-1}|}{K}<\varepsilon/2$$ Put $M=\max\{N,K\}$, then
$$\left|\frac{u_1+\dots+u_M}{M}-l\right|\leq\frac{|u_1-l|+\dots+|u_M-l|}{M}$$
$$<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{|u_N-l|+\dots+|u_M-l|}{M}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{(M-N+1)\varepsilon}{2M}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: This is basically right except for a few details. For one, you need to prove the inequality for all $n > M$, not for just for $M$.  You might also show an extra step justifying the inequality in the second to last line.  And you also presumably mean $|u_{N-1} -l |$ where you have $|u_{N-1}|$.

Comment: No credit seems rather harsh; I was not considered an easy grader, and I’d probably have given $6$ out of $10$.